# enabling and disabling menus based on other input

Tags: jquery, html-select

I had this working using the code above, thanks to help here on SO.  However, I want to modify it such that when a user selects "December" from the month begin menu, the month end menu is disabled with "December" displayed.

Also, if a user goes back and selects a different month from the month begin menu, I want to enable the month end menu again.

I've been trying with various if statements, but I can't seem to get it to work with my admittedly limited skills.

Thanks!

[JSFiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/njNwN/8/)

```
$("select[name='monthSelect']").attr('disabled', 'disabled');

$("select[name='catFrequency']").change(function () {
    var jSelect1=$("select[name='monthSelect']");

    if(jSelect1.attr('disabled')) {
      jSelect1.removeAttr('disabled');
      $('#recurBegin').find("option[value='']").remove();
      $('#recurEnd').find("option[value='']").remove();
      $('#recurEnd').find("option[value='12']").prop('selected', true);
    }
    else
    {
      jSelect1.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
      $("#recurBegin").prepend("<option value='' selected='selected'></option>");
      $("#recurEnd").prepend("<option value='' selected='selected'></option>");
    }
});
    var end = $('#recurEnd');
    $('#recurBegin').change(function () {
    var index = $(this).find('option:selected').index();
    end.find('option').show();
    end.find('option:lt(' + (index + 1) + ')').hide();
});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>[**fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/BwW22/)</kbd>

```
var end = $('#recurEnd');
$('#recurBegin').change(function () {
    if (this.value == 12) {//if month selected is December
        end.val(12);// set End month to December
        end.prop('disabled', true);//disable month end
    } else {
        var index = $(this).find('option:selected').index();
        end.prop('disabled', false);//enable month end
        end.find('option').show();
        end.find('option:lt(' + (index + 1) + ')').hide();
        end.find('option:eq(' + ++index + ')').prop('selected', true);
    }
});
```

[.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)